# Adding a second filter to a listview

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter, searchview

I have a Fragment in my app which includes a custom listview of artists.
This custom listview is connected to custom filter which filters the artist names by a searchview.

Now i want to add a second searchview which will filter the custom listview by another paramenter.

How can i create a second filter in my adapter so every searchview will filter it differently, but its own parameter ?

this is the current filter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

private Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        copyList();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length()==0){
            suggestions.addAll(namesFull);
        }
        else {
            suggestions.clear();
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (String s : namesFull){
                if (s.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    suggestions.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = suggestions;
        results.count = suggestions.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        clear();
        addAll((List)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};

private void copyList() {
    if (namesFull.size()==0) {
        namesFull.addAll(BandsList);
    }
}
```

and this is the filter reference from the searchview :

```
nameFilter.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            artistsAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            artistsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to figure a way to solve this.
What i did was to make the different SearchViews define the same variable by a string representing a number ("1", "2", "3"...) so i could differentiate between them.

Then, under the getFilter i add an if statement which checks this variable and return the custom Filter class needed.

that way, each SearchView filters the list in a different way.

Hope it helps someone.